# Reduce if block conditions using ES6 or ES7

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I wrote this if block but am not fully satisfied with it. Is there a way to further reduce the lines and still be readable leveraging ES6 or ES7?

```
export default function validation(str, props) {
  const {
    length, minLength, maxLength, required,
  } = props;

  if ((required && str.length === 0) || // check string length only if required is defined
    (length && str.length !== length) || // check if string length matches only if length is defined
    (minLength && str.length < minLength) || // check if less than minLength only if minLength is defined
    (maxLength && str.length > maxLength)) { // check if greater than maxLength only if maxlength is defined
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Maybe a `switch` statement would help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `if` expression is supposed to be boolean, and the function returns boolean value according to it, `if` can be omitted.

Code can be made self-documenting by introducing intermediate variables:

```
function validation(str, props) {
  const {
    length, minLength, maxLength, required,
  } = props;

  const isEmpty = (required && str.length === 0);
  const isDifferentLength = (length && str.length !== length);
  ...

  return !(isEmpty || isDifferentLength || ...);
}
```

Comment: I like this and was in the middle of writing something similar (using functions instead though). The main point I see is that this isn't really an ES6+ issue but rather a code organization issue. Better to change how the code is arranged than try anything more elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

You can shorten the function by destructuring props. You can also return the boolean result directly.

```
export default function validation(str, { length, minLength, maxLength, required }) {

  return !((required && str.length === 0)        ||
           (length && str.length !== length)     ||
           (minLength && str.length < minLength) ||
           (maxLength && str.length > maxLength))
}
```

If you use an arrow function, you can also remove the return.

```
const validation = (str, { length, minLength, maxLength, required }) =>
  !((required && str.length === 0)        ||
    (length && str.length !== length)     ||
    (minLength && str.length < minLength) ||
    (maxLength && str.length > maxLength))
```

Comment: It should be noticed that having `props` is beneficial because it can be debugged, this especially applies to arrows.

Comment: Definitely. Debugging arrows is always a pain, and I agree that your decision to break up the logic into intermediate variables is correct. The question was to reduce lines, so I thought I would add some possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

The most succinct way I've found is by using object destructuring default values:

```
function validate(str, props) {
  const { length = str.length, minLength = length, maxLength = length, required } = props; 

  return (!required || !!str.length) && str.length >= minLength && str.length <= maxLength;
}
```